# Prove that if X is finite, then X* is a basis for the vector space V* over F.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, ring-homomorphism

Here is the full statement of the problem:

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, $X$ be a basis for $V$, and $V$* $=Hom_{F}(V,F)$, which is a vector space over $F$. For each $x\in X$, denote $f_{x}$ the unique element of $V$* such that

$$f_{x}(y) = 
\left\{\begin{array}{11}
1_{F} & x=y\\
0_{F} & x\ne y \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Let $X$* $=\left\{f_{x} | x\in X\right\}$. Prove that if $X$ is finite, then $X$* is a basis for the vector space $V$* over $F$.

So I know that I need to prove that $X$* is a linearly independent set and that $X$* generates $V$* but I am at a loss as to how this could be done. Any suggestions to get me started would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: To prove $X^*$ is linearly independent:  Use the definition of "linearly independent". What happens when you start writing that proof?

Comment: To prove that the set $X^*$ generates $V^*$: use that any element of $\text{Hom}_F(V,F)$ is uniquely defined by giving its value on the basis elements of $X$. How can you use that fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $f \in V^* $. How could we write $f$ as a linear combination of $f_x$. First notice that if $v \in V$, since $X$ is a basis (lets say $X = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$), $v = v_1x_1+...+v_n x_n$, where $v_i \in F$. First notice that
$$
f_{x_i}(v) = v_i
$$
This means that
$$
f(v) = f( v_1x_1+...+v_1x_n) = v_1f(x_1)+...+v_nf(x_n) = f_{x_1}(v)f(x_1)+...+f_{x_n}(v)f(x_n)
$$
What does this say about the funnctios $f_{x_i}$ spanning $V^*$?

For the linear independence think about what happens if $\lambda_i \in F$ and
$$
\lambda_1 f_{x_1}+...+\lambda_n f_{x_n} =0
$$
This would need to hold for every $w \in V$...
$$
\lambda_1 f_{x_1}(w)+...+\lambda_n f_{x_n}(w) =0
$$

Comment: In your last statement don't the $f_{x_{i}}(w)$ all vanish except when $x_{i} = w$ in accordance with the definition of $f_{x}$? That would at least guarantee that $\lambda_{i} = 0$ for some $i$. How do we guarantee $\lambda_{i}=0$ for all $i$?

Comment: Also, in your question above, the functions $f_{x_{i}}=v_{i}$ are clearly the scalar constants from $F$ which are identically zero when $v\ne x_{i}$ and $1_{F}$ when $v=x_{i}$.